# Yammer platform_js_sdk.js stopped working suddenly

Tags: javascript, yammer

About 6 months ago I implemented Yammer Js library and it was working with our webapp which is using require.js.

Recently, our app is not working. when I remove the script tag from header which comes before require.js everything gets back to normal.

Do I need to change something??

**UPDATE**:

I donno why but there is something is yam object that conflicts with require.js, I debugged and whenever my code reaches to the function below it returns.
The reason is yam.define is not type of undefined. (so far this is my best guess)

```
    if (typeof define !== 'undefined') {
        //If a define is already in play via another AMD loader,
        //do not overwrite.
        return;
    }
```

I would appreciate any help.

****UPDATE****

Yammer Community should be more active.

Answer (score 0):

have you made changes as suggested by their new API: https://developer.yammer.com/upgrading-to-the-new-yammer-js-sdk/

Comment: nahhh, didn't help, even though I noticed that I'm missing "data-page="page-custom-php"" , I added  it but no luck. but thanks for the reply.

Comment: [link] https://developer.yammer.com/yammer-sdks/#javascript-sdk , why Follow & Like section is blank????